# Unable to delete from database

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013, delete-row

Unable to delete data from database in vb.net using SQL Server.

Here is my code for deletion, can you tell me where I have gone wrong?

Name of the table is `OneToOne`:

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    cn.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = " DELETE * FROM OneToOne WHERE SrNo = " & DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End With
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Conversation Deleted")
    End If
    cn.Close()
    showdata()
End Sub
```

Comment: Ack. Before you do do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. My little friend bobby tables like to wreak havoc on systems like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Try taking out the `*`, it is not needed in a DELETE query, though I'm not sure that's the sole cause of the problem.

Comment: try to log theDataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).ValueDataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value,  and see what value is returning

Comment: @SeanLange i've taken out..it's working but data is deleted step by step u can delete one at a time..i want that if i press button the whole should be deleted

Comment: you should have a look at the syntax of delete statement

Comment: @ it's showing syntax error here-> "*"

Comment: Did you try what @TabAlleman suggested?

Comment: @nscheaffer yes, it's working ..u can delete one at at time..n, i want to delete the whole data

Comment: @Nitin cmd.ExecuteNonQuery -> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() typo ??

Comment: If you want to delete all of the data then get rid of the where clause. I must be missing something here.

Comment: @0x3l337 i've taken i as integer

Comment: @Nitin shouldn't it be like ` i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` ?

Comment: @0x3l337 actually..ok i'm trying

Answer (score 2):

To delete all rows at once, you can iterate through the selected rows and build a comma-separated string of the `Cell(0)` values.

Then instead of using `WHERE srNo =` , use `WHERE srNo IN ({your string})`

At least, this is the way to do it following your current approach.   A better way would be to pass a table-valued parameter to a stored procedure, but that's a broad subject that you would need to research.

And, as with most programming questions, there are multiple other ways this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

on_button_click

```
s = "DELETE FROM OneToOne WHERE SrNo IN(val1,val2.....valn)" 
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(s, cn)
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       If i > 0 Then
            MsgBox("yup")
        End If
        cn.Close()
```

val1,val2.. are your SrNo values. It's on you how you retrieve/provide SrNo values